# How does the variance of a sample relate to the population from which it was drawn?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance

let $X_1, X_2.....,X_n$ be iid random variables. Define the sample mean: $\bar{X}=(X_1+X_2...+X_n)/n$

Now, the sampling distribution of the sample mean has a variance given by:

\begin{align}
var(\bar{X})&=var[(X_1+X_2........+X_n)/n]\\
         &=1/n^2[var(X_1)+var(X_2)..........+var(X_n)]\\
         &=1/n^2[(\sigma)^2+(\sigma)^2+..........+(\sigma)^2]
 \end{align}

Why is $var(X_1)=var(X_2)=......=var(X_n)=\sigma^2$? What is the relation of $\sigma^2$ to the population from which the sample $X_1,X_2,X_3...X_n$ was drawn.

Comment: There is no concept of the "variance of the sample" as you alluded to before. Neither does a population vary. Each observation has a variance, since the sample of size $n$ could be repeatedly drawn and that observation's value differs with each sample. It is because we have a sample that we are able to estimate a variance.

Answer (score 2):

You have started the post with the assumption that $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d, namely, independent *identically* distributed. It is worth to add that you are assuming that $var(X)=\sigma^2 < \infty$, hence $var(X_i)=\sigma^2$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: My question is how can we assume that a sample X1, which is a subset of the population have the same variance as that of the population? Is the assumption not flawed?

Comment: "X1" does not refer to a "subset of the population": it is a *random variable.*